# RFE selects different variables for the same notebook in jupyter and colab

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, feature-selection

I am running a same notebook in Google Colab and Jupyter. I want to select features using RFE for Multiple Linear Regression. I am using the 'sklearn.feature_selection' library for the same. But the issue is both of these are giving different selected features.

I tried searching if there is some parameter to set that I am missing but found nothing.